# Why does the Radius of Convergence prove the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Tags: complex-analysis

> The radius of convergence of $ \sum a_n (x-x_0)^n $ is given by 
>   $$ \frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| $$
>   if the limit exists in the extended reals.

[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using Radius of Convergence]
Now, $1 = p(z)f(z).$ Thus, $a_0 b_0 = 1$. This is the basis step. Assume there is some coefficient such that $|b_k|>cr^k.$ Velleman \cite{Velle} claims we can always find another. Suppose there are no more. Then the coefficient of $z^{k+n}$ in $p(z)f(z)$ is
$$a_0 b_{k+n} + a_1 b_{k+n -1} + ... + a_n b_k = 0$$

Thus, as we have $|b_j| > cr^j$ in this range, we have the coefficient satisfies, 
$$|a_0|r^n + |a_1|r^{n-1} + ... + |a_{n-1}|r \le |a_n|$$ if $$r \le \min \left \{ 1, {|a_n| \over |a_0| + ... + |a_{n-1}|} \right \} $$

This will give that

$$|b_k| = { a_0 b_{k+n} + ... + a_{n-1} b_{k+1} \over |a_n|}$$
$$ \le   { a_0 b_{k+n} + ... + a_{n-1} b_{k+1} \over |a_n|} \le cr^k $$

for sufficiently small.
Let $z= \frac{1}{r}.$ Then 
$$ |b_k z^k| = \frac{|b_k|}{r^k} >c$$

This is true for infinitely many $k$, hence the power series diverges, contradicting assumption that the function is analytic and its power series converges everywhere.

> I don't understand how proving the function is analytic and its power series converges everywhere means that:
>   For $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ If $f(z)= a_0 + a_1z + ... +a_n z^n$ there exists some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $f(z_0) = 0$.

Comment: A relatively easy way to prove FTA for a polynomial $p(z)$ is to assume that it's false and then use the mean value property for the entire function $1/p(z)$...

Comment: It looks like the proof was probably by contradiction: something like "if $p$ has no roots then $f=1/p$ is a bounded, entire function".